# Prove given function is not injective

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, roots, rouches-theorem

I want to show that $f(z) = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}+\frac{z}{(1+z)^2})$ is not injective in the unit disk.

What I have done so far:

Simplify $f(z)$, $f(z) = \frac{z^3+z}{(z^2-1)^2}$

Setting $f(z) = f(w)$

$\frac{z^3+z}{(z^2-1)^2} = \frac{w^3+w}{(w^2-1)^2}$

$(z^3+z)(w^2-1)^2-(w^3+w)(z^2-1)^2=0$

Factor the expression to get: $(w-z)(zw-1)((zw+1)^2+(z+w)^2) = 0$

So I really need to show there is a pair of $z, w \in \mathbb{D}$ that satisfies $(zw+1)^2+(z+w)^2= 0$. I have trouble proceed from here. In addition, is there an easier way to do this? I thought of Rouche's Theorem but didn't get anything meaningful.

Comment: Double pole at $1$ and $-1$ immediately show that as for an injective function on the disc you cannot have more than 2 single poles or one double pole (essentially you can have half the pole image inside half outside the disc so that's why you can have 2 either split in 2 singles or one double but no more)

Comment: I have never heard of this theorem about no more than 1 double pole, can you give me a link/reference or elaborate more on this?

Comment: The local representation at a pole sends a neighborhood onto a neighborhood of infty, so image contains the exterior of a large disc; double pole same going around twice, triple pole three times etc; since the pole is on the boundary, the inside unit disc goes onto half of that (polar coordinates make it precise) and since we cannot have superposition by injectivity we cannot go three or more times at poles, so we cannot have a triple pole, 3 simple ones, a simple and a double and of course anything more; we can and do have double poles (koebe) or 2 simple ones (the odd transform of koebe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the obvious route. $(zw + 1)^2 = -(z+w)^2$ is implied by $zw+1 = i(z+w)$, so collecting coefficients it would suffice for $z(w-i) - iw + 1 = 0$ or

$$z = \frac{iw - 1}{w - i} = i \left(\frac{w + i}{w - i}\right).$$

Try $w = it$ to obtain

$$z = i\left(\frac{t + 1}{t - 1}\right)$$

and for $-1 < t < 0$ we have $|z|< 1$.

Explicitly, you can pick $w = -i/2$ and $z = -i/3$. We have $f(z) = f(w) = -12i/50$.